# Camapign Member picklist value

Tags: force.com

When we create a new campaign record , when clicking advanced button itz default value is sent so how to set  for all campaign member picklist new value as default.

Comment: can u please be clear on your question and try to add more details

Answer (score 0):

From the campaign, after creation, Click Advanced Setup.
From there, you can edit the picklist options and set the defaults.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_def.htm